# How can I get the values of json if it returns an array of result?

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I want to know how can I retrieve the values from the json if the json returns an array of result?

Note: the first array is not the same length of the second array but the first array is will be always be less than the second array

Here's what I do as of now and get this error:

[image]

Here's my jquery code:

```
success: function(data){
            var toAppend = '';
            if(typeof data === "object"){
                for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                    toAppend += '<tr><td colspan="2">'+data[0][i]['m-asin'][0]+'</td></tr>';
                    toAppend += '<tr><td>'+data[1][i]['asin'][0]+'</td><td>'+data[1][i]['size'][0]+'</td></tr>';
                }
                $('.data-results').append(toAppend);
            }
        }
```

ANd I think no need for php code since it is working because it returns the expected results. Any help will be a big thing thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data[0][i]` gives you the i-th property of the first data element. You'll need to revert it: `data[i][0]`.

Or otherwise, you'll need to alter the loop, to get the number of elements in data[0]:

```
for(var i=0; i<data[0].length; i++){
```

Comment: data[i][1] is undefined I get this result :#

Comment: Yeah, the relationship between your code and and the JSON data wasn't exactly clear to me, but I think you only need to alter the for loop. You will then get the length of `data[0]`, so you can then ask for `data[0][i]` and `data[1][i]`. In your posted code you get the length of `data` (top level), which is 2.

Comment: if remove the data[0][i]['m-asin'][0] the data[1][0]['asin'][0] will display but I really need to display it both how should I do this